# Google People API return Grpc status code null

Tags: php, grpc, google-api-php-client, google-people-api

I want to use Grpc Status code instead of Http Status code in Google People API.
I receive a `PersonResponse` object as a response (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/PersonResponse) but when the response is successful i have a null Grpc status code.

```
/** @var GetPeopleResponse $getPeopleResponse */
$getPeopleResponse = $googleSyncService->getBatchGet(['people/c123', 'people/c6712532233844095820']);
foreach ($getPeopleResponse->getResponses() as $personResponse) {
    dump([
        'Grpc Status Code' => $personResponse->getStatus()->getCode(),
        'Http Status Code' => $personResponse->getHttpStatusCode()
    ]);
}
```

With an invalid people ID i got this status codes (as expected) :

```
array:2 [▼
  "Grpc Status Code" => 5
  "Http Status Code" => 404
]
```

With a valid people ID i got this status codes :

```
array:2 [▼
  "Grpc Status Code" => null
  "Http Status Code" => 200
]
```

Why i don't get Grpc Status Code `0` ?
I am using `google/apiclient` version `2.9.2`

Comment: does the people api even support grpc?  if it does thats new to me.

Comment: @DalmTo I juste want to use the Grpc Status Code, because in the link i put in my question it says "httpStatusCode DEPRECATED (Please use status instead)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The People API devs indicated that you should see a `null` status for a successful request.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183335975#comment2

This is not well documented though. I'd recommend filing an issue to make that behavior clear in their API docs.